# odd video bugs turns black but plays in new tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, video

i had no idea what to call this question so if you  want me to edit it at a later time feel free to comment.

I have the most annoying and strange bug in my history as a developer. i will try to explain it as well as i can but if you guys need more info then please tell me and il add additional information.

Case:

My application is using the `Angular` framework. Now my clients are able to upload videos to the page (along with other resources) and then play them back as a slideshow.

Each slide is an element that can be one of these items:

- Video
- Sound
- Document
- Text
- Image

Now i have attempted to create one with 12 different videos.

The slideshow is made up of the following html:

```
<lb-video ng-show="component.component_type_id == 1" resource-token="{{components[i].video_mp4_path}}" media-type="components[i].content_type"></lb-video>
<view-sound ng-if="component.component_type_id == 2" ng-controller="SoundController"></view-sound>
<view-doc ng-if="component.component_type_id == 4" ng-controller="DocumentController"></view-doc>
<view-text ng-if="component.component_type_id == 5" ng-controller="TextController"></view-text>
```

Now the `lb-video` directive looks like this:

**lb-video:**

```
    <div ng-show="dd.isDesktop()">
    <div class="lbVideo inline center-block">

        <video id="player1" src="{{videoPath}}" controls="controls" width="598" height="320">

        </video>

    </div>
</div>

<div ng-show="!dd.isDesktop()">
    <div ng-if="dd.isTablet() && videoPath != null">
        <video width="459" height="320" controls>
            <source src="{{videoPath}}" type="video/mp4">
            Your browser does not support the video tag.
        </video>
    </div>
    <div ng-if="!dd.isTablet() && videoPath != null">
        <video width="250" height="220" controls>
            <source src="{{videoPath}}" type="video/mp4">
            Your browser does not support the video tag.
        </video>
    </div>
</div>
```

With the following `link function`:

```
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
        function init() {
            scope.srcUrl = null;
            scope.videoPath = null;

            $http.get(LRM.getDeviceResource(scope.resourceToken))
                .success(function (response) {
                    scope.srcUrl = response.data;
                }).error(function () {
                $http.get(api.getUrl('fileDecryption', scope.resourceToken)).success(function (response) {
                    scope.srcUrl = response;
                })
            });
            scope.onPlayerReady = function (API) {
                scope.API = API;
            };
            scope.dd = deviceDetector;
            scope.LRM = LRM;
            if (scope.mediaType == null) {
                scope.mediaType = 'video/mp4'; // Fall back function attempts to load it as mp4
            }

            if (scope.resourceToken.match(/user_resources/)) {
                setVideo(scope.resourceToken);
            } else {
                $http.get(LRM.getDirectPath(scope.resourceToken))
                    .success(function (response) {
                        setVideo(response);
                    }).error(function () {
                    $http.get(api.getUrl('fileDecryption', scope.resourceToken)).success(function (response) {
                        setVideo(response);
                    })
                });
            }
        }

        scope.$watch('resourceToken', function (newValue, oldValue) {
            if (newValue) {
                init();
            }
        }, true);

        function setVideo(path) {

            scope.videoPath = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(path);
        }
    }
```

Running the first 6 videoes is no problem. It shows up fine and the videos play.

However no matter how many times i try the 7th video (and forward from that)  turns up like this:

[image]

black screen nothing to do and nothing to show. After this happens all my previous videos (that i have seen) will do the same and i wont be able to play a video untill i have reloaded the page.

HOWEVER if i right click the element and press (open video in new tab)

[image]

It plays perfectly fine:

[image]

This is a really big issue for me since my application is dependent on people uploading x number of videos and plays them to their clients. Does anyone have any idea why this might happen?

Comment: Same behaviour on all browsers? Have you tried to set `preload="none"` on videos to avoid some buffering issue?

Comment: @A.Wolff same on all browsers trying preload now give me a minute

Comment: @A.Wolff preload seem to be working (as far as the test goes) however the caption will be lost when using this right?

Comment: Ya but you could find some logic to load only one video at a time and remove preload attribute (or set to true) each time a video fire `loadeddata` event. It should be quite transparent for user. See quick example: http://jsfiddle.net/rzL8wc1g/

Comment: **EDIT** as i can see, still not working on chrome, stopping at 7th video :(

Comment: Looks like using `preload="metadata"` would fix it: http://jsfiddle.net/rzL8wc1g/1/    ref: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/video.html#video.attrs.preload

Comment: @A.Wolff Mine works with preload=none